# vim syntax highlighting: match, contains

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, contains

I am trying to make an angularjs syntax highlighting file for vim.  A piece of the file is:

```
syn match ngMethods                /\.[0-9A-Za-z_\-\$]\+\s*\((\|=\)/ contains=AngularMethods
syn keyword AngularMethods         contained $addControl $anchorScroll $animate ...

syn match ngObjMethods             /^\s*[0-9A-Za-z_\-\$]\+\s*:/ contains=AngularObjectMethods
syn keyword AngularObjectMethods   contained compile controller link ...
```

etc...

Down below I have:

```
hi def link AngularMethods       Function

hi def link AngularObjectMethods Function
```

The first regular expression (for `AngularMethods`) is supposed to capture things like `$addControl` in the following:

```
myelement.$addControl()
myelement.$addControl = function ()
```

The second regular expression (for `AngularObjectMethods`) captures things like `compile` in:

```
    compile : function () {}
```

The `AngularMethods` one does NOT work but the latter one does.  Can anyone see the problem?  I've also tried using the regexes:

```
/\.\zs[0-9A-Za-z_\-\$]\+\ze\s*\((\|=\)/

/\.[0-9A-Za-z_\-\$]\+\s*\((\|=\)\@=/
```

The former matches the exact word.  The latter is something I saw in another syntax file.  Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

Kent (below) was correct about the keyword.  This uncovered the real problem which is that I have another regex:

```
syn match ngProperties          /\.[0-9A-Za-z_\-\$]\+\s*[^(=]/ contains=AngularProperties
syn keyword AngularProperties   contained $attr $dirty $error ...
```

which is supposed to be the complement of the ngMethods regex.  If I comment out the `ngProperties` regex, the `ngMethods` regex works.  This means `ngProperties` is bad.  It is supposed to catch things like `$attr` in:

```
var myAttribute = element.$attr;
```

I will try to fix this.  Can someone post the correct regex just in case?

Comment: Could you drill down teh problem to smaller code. You want to find AngularMethods, how does this looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is not the problem for your syntax.

What **very likely** the cause of the problem is, your `iskeyword` option doesn't have the dollar (`$`) sign.

what you can test is:

- remove the `$` from `contained $addControl $anchorScrol`, to see if it will work

or

- execute: `set iskeyword+=$` to see if it works.

Comment: You were correct, but I have another problem.  See edit above!